# Create group of numbers with total sum 12

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, recursive-query

The table in Bigquery has 100 or more digits from 0.5 to 6 in 0.5 increments in the queue from 1 to 100.
You need to create groups of numbers in turn. In each group, the sum of the digits is 12.
In the picture, an example of a table, group 1 should consist of the digits 1, 2, 3, 6 which add up to 12. The missing numbers 4, 5 should get into the next group
I will be grateful for any hints and ideas.

I tried to group them first to get the sum less than or equal to 12 and add the missing digits in the second step to get 12 in each group

| order_num | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 4.5 |
| 3 | 5.0 |
| 4 | 3.5 |
| 5 | 3.5 |
| 6 | 0.5 |
| 7 | 1.5 |
| 8 | 4.5 |
| 9 | 4.5 |
| 10 | 1.5 |

```
   WITH cte AS (SELECT
    order_num,
    num,
    SUM(num) OVER (ORDER BY order_num) AS cumulative_sum
    FROM
    `ms_jzs6s5.test_numbers`)
, groupHours as (
    SELECT

  order_num,
  num,
  cumulative_sum,
  CASE
    WHEN cumulative_sum <= CAST(12 AS FLOAT64) THEN num
    ELSE num - GREATEST(cumulative_sum - CAST(12 AS FLOAT64), 0)
  END AS plan,
  IF(MOD(CAST(cumulative_sum AS NUMERIC), 12) <> 0, CEIL(cumulative_sum / 12), CEIL(cumulative_sum / 12) + 1) AS group_num AS group_num,
FROM
  cte 
)

, Lastgroup as (
SELECT
groupHours.*
FROM
  groupHours
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(group_num) maxgroup
  FROM groupHours
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(group_num) - 1 maxgroup
  FROM groupHours) ON groupHours.group_num = maxgroup
)

, groupLastHours as (
SELECT
group_num,
12 - SUM(num) AS lastHour

FROM
  groupHours
GROUP BY group_num
)

(
SELECT 1 as iteration, * 
FROM groupHours

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 iteration, 
Lastgroup.*
FROM Lastgroup
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    groupLastHours.group_num,
    Lastgroup.num,
    MIN(order_num) order_num,
      FROM groupLastHours
      LEFT JOIN Lastgroup ON lastHour = Lastgroup.num
      GROUP BY 
      groupLastHours.group_num,
    groupLastHours.lastHour,
    Lastgroup.num
) lsh ON Lastgroup.num = lsh.num
)
ORDER BY group_num, iteration
```

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all information to your question as editable text. Please also show the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own so far

Comment: Unfortunately I can't insert image here. I added my sql

Comment: Please don’t use images at all - add everything to your question as editable text

Comment: ok, I added this as text

Comment: do you need to respect the order or numbers can be taken from any position?

Comment: it is necessary to observe the order

Comment: BigQuery is not the right tool for solving constrain problem. You want to solve the "Knapsack problem", for wich there are great tools.

Comment: I agree with @Samuel that BigQuery is not the right tool to solve this problem. However, can you clarify what is the acceptance criteria for your problem. Are you trying to find out all possible combinations that would create a 12 sum or you happy with finding the maximum number of groups. E.g. considering the `sum` of your numbers is 31 you know for sure you cannot have more than two groups. are you happy with any two (if possible) or you want them all. Without analyzing all combinations also 3,4,5 group as well as 7,8,9,10 group as well as 1,4,5,7,10 will add up to12

Comment: you do not need to consider all possible combinations, need to sum up the numbers in turn to get a total of 12

in the example it is:
Group 1 = 1,2,3 (here we can't take 4, because the sum exceeds 12, we skip 4, 5), 6
(there are now numbers 4,5,7,8,9,10 in the queue and so on up to 100) 
Group 2 = 4,5,7,10,11 (assume that the 11th num is 2.0)
Group 3 = 8,9,...

Comment: Your group are 1,2,3 - 4,5,7,10,11 (if 11 is 2.0). if 11 is not 2.0, possible 1,2,3 -7,8,9,10. No groups contain 4 and 5. Do you skip 4 and 5?

Comment: There is no skips. I should put 4 and 5 to Group 3.  If there is only 10 numbers then last group will contain numbers with sum less than 12. I should use all numbers in order.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a smart grouping but it creates groups cumulatively with the sum not over 12 per group ...

```sql
with t as (
  select * from unnest([
    struct(1 as order_num, 2.0 as num),
    (2,4.5), (3,5.0), (4,3.5), (5,3.5), (6,0.5), (7,1.5), (8,4.5), (9,4.5), (10,1.5)
  ])
)

select * 
  ,sum(num) over (order by order_num) as cumusum
  ,cast(floor(sum(num) over (order by order_num)/12) as int64) as g
  ,sum(num) over (order by order_num) - cast(floor(sum(num) over (order by order_num)/12) as int64)*12 as g_fill_sum
from t
```

maybe it's something someone can turn into a better solution ...

Answer (score 0):

There solution with recursive query.
Used 2 recursive queries and temporary table to isolate these recursions.
Example for SQL Server. I see, it is possible adopt to BigQuery.
For test used your data (without 11th num is 2.0).

More details in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u5HIB4Z7)

First, all groups with sum=12

```
with r1 as(
select 0 lvl,order_num head,order_num,num
  ,num as grsum
  ,cast(order_num as varchar(1000)) path
  ,power(2,order_num) mask1,0  mask2
from test
  
  union all
  
select lvl+1 lvl,r.head,t.order_num,t.num
  ,r.grsum+t.num as grsum
  ,cast(path+','+cast(t.order_num as varchar) as varchar(1000)) path
  ,case when t.order_num<60 then  mask1+power(2,t.order_num)
   else  mask1
   end mask1
  ,case when t.order_num>60 then  mask2+power(2,t.order_num)
   else  mask2
   end mask2
from r1 r inner join test t on t.order_num>r.order_num
  and (r.grsum+t.num)<=12
  and lvl<20
)
insert into #tmp
select * from r1 where grsum=12;
```

Result is - possible groups

| lvl | head | order_num | num | grsum | path | mask1 | mask2 | mx1 | mx2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 6 | 0.5 | 12 | 1,2,3,6 | 78 | 0 | 0x000000000000004E | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,2,4,6,10 | 1110 | 0 | 0x0000000000000456 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,2,4,6,7 | 214 | 0 | 0x00000000000000D6 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,2,5,6,10 | 1126 | 0 | 0x0000000000000466 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,2,5,6,7 | 230 | 0 | 0x00000000000000E6 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,3,4,10 | 1050 | 0 | 0x000000000000041A | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 1 | 7 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,3,4,7 | 154 | 0 | 0x000000000000009A | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,3,5,10 | 1066 | 0 | 0x000000000000042A | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 1 | 7 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,3,5,7 | 170 | 0 | 0x00000000000000AA | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 | 4.5 | 12 | 1,3,6,8 | 330 | 0 | 0x000000000000014A | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 1 | 9 | 4.5 | 12 | 1,3,6,9 | 586 | 0 | 0x000000000000024A | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,4,5,7,10 | 1202 | 0 | 0x00000000000004B2 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 | 4.5 | 12 | 1,4,6,7,8 | 466 | 0 | 0x00000000000001D2 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 9 | 4.5 | 12 | 1,4,6,7,9 | 722 | 0 | 0x00000000000002D2 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,4,6,8,10 | 1362 | 0 | 0x0000000000000552 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,4,6,9,10 | 1618 | 0 | 0x0000000000000652 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 | 4.5 | 12 | 1,5,6,7,8 | 482 | 0 | 0x00000000000001E2 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 9 | 4.5 | 12 | 1,5,6,7,9 | 738 | 0 | 0x00000000000002E2 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,5,6,8,10 | 1378 | 0 | 0x0000000000000562 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 1,5,6,9,10 | 1634 | 0 | 0x0000000000000662 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 | 0.5 | 12 | 2,4,5,6 | 116 | 0 | 0x0000000000000074 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 2,7,8,10 | 1412 | 0 | 0x0000000000000584 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 2,7,9,10 | 1668 | 0 | 0x0000000000000684 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 3.5 | 12 | 3,4,5 | 56 | 0 | 0x0000000000000038 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 3 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 3,4,6,7,10 | 1240 | 0 | 0x00000000000004D8 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 3 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 3,5,6,7,10 | 1256 | 0 | 0x00000000000004E8 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 | 4.5 | 12 | 4,5,6,8 | 368 | 0 | 0x0000000000000170 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 4 | 9 | 4.5 | 12 | 4,5,6,9 | 624 | 0 | 0x0000000000000270 | 0x0000000000000000 |
| 3 | 7 | 10 | 1.5 | 12 | 7,8,9,10 | 1920 | 0 | 0x0000000000000780 | 0x0000000000000000 |

This rows saved to table #tmp.

Next part - concatenate groups, not intersected by order_num. For intersection check used bit mask (mask's).

```
with r2 as(
select 0 l2,head
  ,cast(path as varchar(1000)) path
  ,mask1,mask2
from #tmp -- left join (select 1 xx)x on 1=1
  union all
  select l2+1,t.head
  ,cast(r.path+'-'+t.path  as varchar(1000)) path
  ,(r.mask1 | t.mask1) mask1
  ,(r.mask2 | t.mask2) mask2
  from r2 r inner join #tmp t -- (select * from r1 t inner join (select 1 xx)x on 1=1 ) t
   on t.head>r.head
    and (r.mask1 & t.mask1)=0 and (r.mask2 & t.mask2)=0
    and (l2+1)<5
)
select distinct path from r2;
```

Result is (part of result) - possible groups and groups of group

| path |
| --- |
| 1,2,3,6-7,8,9,10 |
| 1,3,6,8-2,7,9,10 |
| 1,3,6,9-2,7,8,10 |
| 2,4,5,6-7,8,9,10 |
| 2,7,8,10-3,4,5 |
| 2,7,8,10-4,5,6,9 |
| 2,7,9,10-3,4,5 |
| 2,7,9,10-4,5,6,8 |
| 3,4,5-7,8,9,10 |

Answer (score 0):

Here a recursive solution NOT calculating all combinaisons and using a queue mechanism, it's for ORACLE but just change LISTAGG() by the string aggregation function of your DB and NVL2() by ... and it should work:

```
with cte(queue, nqueue, mx, rsum, grp, oqueue, noqueue, solution, stop, cyckechk) as
(
    select listagg(num,',') within group(order by order_num), '', 12, 0, 1, 
        listagg(order_num,',') within group(order by order_num), '', '',
        0, listagg(num,',') within group(order by order_num) || '//0'
    from test_numbers 
    
    union all
    
    select
        -- queue
        case when queue is null then
            nqueue
        else
            case when rsum = mx then
                nqueue || nvl2(nqueue,',','') || queue
            else
                case when instr(queue,',') > 0 then substr(queue,instr(queue,',')+1) else '' end
            end
        end,
        
        -- nqueue
        case when queue is null then
            ''
        else
            case when rsum = mx then
                ''
            else
                case when 
                    case when instr(queue,',') > 0 then to_number(substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1))
                    else to_number(queue) end + rsum > mx 
                then
                    nqueue || nvl2(nqueue,',','') || 
                    case when instr(queue,',') > 0 then substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1) else queue end
                else
                    nqueue
                end
            end
        end,
        
        mx, 
        
        -- running sum
        case when queue is null then
            0
        else 
            case when rsum = mx then
                0
            else
                case when 
                    case when instr(queue,',') > 0 then to_number(substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1))
                    else to_number(queue) end + rsum > mx 
                then
                    rsum
                else
                    rsum + to_number(substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1))
                end
            end
        end,
        
        -- groupe
        case when queue is null then
            grp + 1
        else
            case when rsum = mx then
                grp + 1
            else 
                grp
            end
        end,
    
        -- oqueue
        case when oqueue is null then
            noqueue
        else
            case when rsum = mx then
                noqueue || nvl2(noqueue,',','') || oqueue
            else
                case when instr(oqueue,',') > 0 then substr(oqueue,instr(oqueue,',')+1) else '' end
            end
        end,
        
        -- noqueue
        case when oqueue is null then
            ''
        else
            case when rsum = mx then
                ''
            else
                case when 
                    case when instr(queue,',') > 0 then to_number(substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1))
                    else to_number(queue) end + rsum > mx 
                then
                    noqueue || nvl2(noqueue,',','') || 
                    case when instr(oqueue,',') > 0 then substr(oqueue,1,instr(oqueue,',')-1) else oqueue end
                else
                    noqueue
                end
            end
        end,
        
        -- solution
        case when queue is null then
            solution
        else 
            case when rsum = mx then
                solution
            else
                case when 
                    case when instr(queue,',') > 0 then to_number(substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1))
                    else to_number(queue) end + rsum > mx 
                then
                    solution
                else
                    solution || chr(10) ||
                    case when instr(oqueue,',') > 0 then substr(oqueue,1,instr(oqueue,',')-1)
                    else oqueue end
                    || '=' ||
                    case when instr(queue,',') > 0 then substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1)
                    else queue end
                    || ' in ' || grp
                end
            end
        end
        || case when instr(queue,',') = 0 and nqueue is null then chr(10) || oqueue || '=' || queue || ' in ' || (grp+1) end
        ,
        
        -- stop
        case when queue is null and nqueue is null 
        then 1 
        else
            case when instr(queue,',') = 0 and nqueue is null 
            then 1
            else
                0 
            end
        end,
        
        -- cycle check
        case when queue is null then
            nqueue
        else
            case when rsum = mx then
                nqueue || nvl2(nqueue,',','') || queue
            else
                substr(queue,instr(queue,',')+1)
            end
        end
        || '/' ||
        case when queue is null then
            ''
        else
            case when rsum = mx then
                ''
            else
                case when 
                    case when instr(queue,',') > 0 then to_number(substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1))
                    else to_number(queue) end + rsum > mx 
                then
                    nqueue || nvl2(nqueue,',','') || substr(queue,1,instr(queue,',')-1)
                else
                    nqueue
                end
            end
        end
        || '/' || rsum
    from cte
    where stop = 0
)
cycle cyckechk set is_cycle to '1' default '0'
select solution from cte
where queue is null and instr(nqueue,',') = 0
;


1=2 in 1
2=4.5 in 1
3=5 in 1
6=.5 in 1
4=3.5 in 2
5=3.5 in 2
7=1.5 in 2
10=1.5 in 2
12=.5 in 2
15=1 in 2
8=4.5 in 3
9=4.5 in 3
11=3 in 3
13=3 in 4
14=2.5 in 4
16=1 in 4
17=4 in 4
18=5 in 5
```

The solution being the translation in SQL of the following PROLOG logic, this should help to understand the above:

```
/* Q current queue, NQ next queue, Max, S current sum, G current group */
binpack([], [], _, _, _).
    
binpack([], NQ, M, _, G) :-
    G1 is G + 1,
    binpack(NQ, [], M, 0, G1).
    
binpack( Q, NQ, M, M, G) :-
    append(NQ, Q, NQ1),
    G1 is G + 1,
    binpack(NQ1, [], M, 0, G1).

binpack( [H|T], NQ, M, S, G) :-
    H + S =< M,
    print([H,G]),
    S1 is S + H,
    binpack(T, NQ, M, S1, G).

binpack( [H|T], NQ, M, S, G) :-
    H + S > M,
    append(NQ, [H], NQ1),
    binpack(T, NQ1, M, S, G).
```